# Neural Networks, a simple counter

Tags: neural-network

Is it possible to create an ANN, which takes some data in the output just increments some counter? For example, every pass would increase the number given by a binary representation using 4 output neurons. I remember reading that the output should be same given the same input. So is that possible?

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://stats.stackexchange.com , lots of machine learning guys over there.

Comment: can anybody move this article there or should i just ask the same question here and close this one?

Comment: why would you want to do something like that?.. and why would you call that a neural network?

Comment: @Qnan Nowhere, it was just a question out of curiosity

Comment: Maybe some neurons need to feed themselves with their outputs so they somehow remember the last iteration but dont change the way the NN work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is actually possible if one sticks to the original notion of a neural network, which is a composition of functions, each taking a weighted sum of the outputs of the previous layer as an input and producing a singe output value. The weights are usually trained to reproduce the known outputs on certain input values. The backpropagation algorithm I believe you are referring to updates the weights in a certain fashion, and the idea of making one of the weights work as a *counter* doesn't really make any sense.